# How to trap startActivity in my android junit test

Tags: java, android, android-intent, junit

I am extending ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 for my unit test. At the end of the unit test, my activity should call startActivity() with an intent.

I want to capture that intent, make sure it got created, and test the extra on the intent.

It seems strange that I have searched and cannot find an example for this. It looks like maybe getInstrumentation().addMonitor() is the way to go, but I can't even find examples of how to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like you want to call [getStartedActivityIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#getStartedActivityIntent()).